# Django admin: overriding form for only add object view

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to override Django Admin form, but only for `add` view and not the `change` view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do it by define the [add_form_template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.add_form_template)

for example

```
class Myadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form_template = 'your_path_to_add_form.html'
```